# PHP regex to check the matching given URL

Tags: php

How do you check if a given URL matches at least a sitename?

I have:

```
$url_to_match = 'http://sub.somesite.com/';
```

I want to say "MATCH found" for input starting with `http://sub.somesite.com` only.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP's [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url = 'http://sub.somesite.com/';
if ('sub.somesite.com' === parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)) {
    // we have a match
}
```

Comment: +1 for the right tool for the job. Depends if the OP wants to validate the scheme too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, did the job well. I was confused with lots of regex approaches :) But this is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

example:

```
function match_url($base,$input)
{
    $base_host = parse_url($base,PHP_URL_HOST);
    $input_host = parse_url($input,PHP_URL_HOST);
    if( $base_host === $input_host ) {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}
$base_url = 'http://sub.somesite.com';
$input_url = 'http://sub.somesite.com//bla/bla';
echo (match_url($base_url,$input_url)) ? "URL matched" : "URL mismatched";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell us what you are doing since this request makes no design sense.

However, to answer the question.

```
if(strpos($url_to_match, 'http://sub.anothersite.com/bla') !== FALSE) print 'bad string';
```

Comment: This is wrong usage of strpos() (syntax error), but yes, based on the question, you need to use strpos(), read here http://lt.php.net/strpos

Comment: @AurelijusValeiša, good catch, I can't believe I forgot the `$haystack`. XD

Comment: I have clarified my question. I am afraid doing checking the opposite is not what I meant. Thanks